# docker-compose volumes with a custom docker file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to mount my code directory using docker volume, but unable to do so.
Here's the relevant section of my docker-compose file.

```
web:
  build: ./web
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  links:
    - db:db
    - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
  volumes:
    - ./web:/usr/src/app
```

**`web`** folder has a DockerFile with the following instructions.

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose up is working without any issues, but I don't see any volumes after start up.

```
root@test-new:/home/django/test# docker inspect test_web | grep -i volume
        "Volumes": null,
        "Volumes": null,
```

Here's the rest of my stack, if that is relevant.

```
elasticsearch
nginx
postgres db
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Docker 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax works.

**volumes:
    - ${PWD}/web:/usr/src/app**

```
web:
  build: ./web
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-aside
  links:
    - db:db
    - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
  volumes:
    - ${PWD}/web:/usr/src/app
  env_file: .env
```

One of the reasons the earlier migrations were not being copied is because I was running the code inside a new container, instead of the container that is currently up.

Instead of

```
docker-compose run --rm web /bin/bash
```

When I tried

```
docker exec -it my_container_name web /bin/bash
```

And then run the migrate command, the newly generated database migration commands are not present on the source directory. It would be ideal to use docker-compose exec, but the current version I am using is below 1.7, so I am using the above interim solution in the mean time.

https://github.com/d11wtq/dockerpty/pull/48